# Mapping performance of Asus Xtion Pro vs Xtion Pro LIVE

Tags: slam, asus-xtion-pro-live, xtion, asus, asus-xtion-pro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I want to buy one of the Asus Xtion sensor models and this question is for to make sure about which model, before i make the purchase.

I want to use one of the models of the **Asus Xtion Pro** sensor ONLY for gmapping (SLAM) and to build 2D maps.
For my application I prefer the device with the minimum required features, meaning that if the RGB sensor is not necessary for my SLAM application then I prefer to ignore it and purchase the "Asus Xtion Pro" *(which comes without-RGB camera)* instead of the "Pro LIVE" RGB-D version.

Is an Asus Xtion Pro (no RGB sensor) able to do the job for **depthimage_to_laserscan** conversion & gmapping slam in order to create 2DCostmaps or do i have to provide both of the RGB and depth_image for that purpose? **PRO or PRO LIVE !?**

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219840/mapping-performance-of-asus-xtion-pro-vs-xtion-pro-live/) by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not need RGB data for anything navigation-stack related.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on 2015-10-26**:
So based on this a Xtion Pro would do! Thank you Paul.